# Issue with Camel-mybatis component (2.17.2)

Tags: apache-camel

I have just started using Apache Camel for an integration project. I am using `camel-mybatis` to persist objects to mysql but the mybatis endpoint fails to resolve with the following Trace message:

> 2016-07-19 15:50:15 TRACE EventHelper:800 - Notifier: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry@5847e0b4 is not enabled for the event: Failed to start Camel: camel-1 due to Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[mybatis:insertDividend?statementType=InsertList] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[timer://foo?repeatCount=1]] -> [SetHeade... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: mybatis://insertDividend?statementType=InsertList due to: Cannot auto create component: mybatis

I have the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: What is the location of your mapping file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install camel-mybatis component into your container. 
features:install camel-mybatis

Following page should give you more details:

http://camel.apache.org/mybatis-example.html